# Pass a matrix between view controllers

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to pass a matrix between view controllers. I finally figured out how to pass Objective-C objects, but matrices aren't Objective-C but rather C.
I tried using extern variables to pass it, but then it asks for the matrix bounds. Is there any way I can pass the matrix or even better, is there an Objective-C version of a matrix?

ViewController1.m

```
extern NSInteger matrix[yMapLength][xMapLength] =
{{0,0,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,2,4,4,4},
{0,1,1,2,3,2,1,1,4,4,3,4,4},
{1,1,2,3,3,2,1,4,1,3,3,4,4},
{1,1,3,3,3,2,4,1,1,1,4,4,4},
{0,1,1,2,2,2,4,4,4,4,4,4,4},
{0,0,1,1,2,2,1,0,0,2,3,4,4},
{4,4,1,1,2,2,1,1,0,1,1,4,4},
{0,4,1,2,2,2,1,1,0,4,4,4,4},
{0,1,2,2,2,2,1,1,0,1,2,4,4},
{0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0,4,4,4}};
```

ViewController2.m

```
extern NSInteger matrix[][];
```

Error: "Array has incomplete element type NSInteger[]"

or I do

ViewController2.m

```
extern NSInteger matrix;
```

then it doesn't recognize matrix as a matrix but as a NSInteger.

Comment: What about `extern NSInteger** matrix;` ?

Comment: With the `extern NSInteger** matrix;` (what does "**" do?), it gets rid of the pre-compiler errors, but:
When I do `NSLog(@"%i",matrix[2][0]);` in ViewController2 it gives me an error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x8)